Subscription class not found even in brand new Rails projects
I was reading the book Agile Web Development with Rails 7 and ran the command
bin/rails generate channel products

Since then in all my Rails apps I get the following Message
Subscription class not found: "ProductsChannel"

Even in brand new projects which I just created with rails new.
I already tried killing the ruby and the rails process on my mac. It seems like action cable is still running in the background somehow? How can I stop this

is there a file somewhere in your app called products_channel.rb? Does it define the class ProductsChannel? Where is it located in the app? You said "I get the following message"... what are you doing when you get this message?
